Having id number in data frame repeat for a variable number of times based on cell value in R
This is the data frame I originally have, the values in t_p and t_c are ages.

I want to make the id repeat the number of times from the start of data collecion (which is age 50), so I need to take t_c age (ignore t_p) and subtract by 50, and that value is the number of times I want a person's id number to repeat, but I am unsure how to do that.
This is a rough structure of how I want to format my data frame.
I want it to show the exact age
I am attempting to make two data frames and bind them but I cannot figure out the repeating id number aspect!

You can try:
result = reframe(df, age=50:floor(t_c),.by = id)

or
library(data.table)
result = setDT(df)[rep(id,floor(t_c)-50)][, .(age=0:.N+50),id]

I'm not sure what you want in the final column. If you want all NA except the last row per id, then you can add this:
mutate(result, t_c = if_else(row_number()==n(),age,NA),.by = id)

or
result[, t_c:=fifelse(age==max(age),age,NA),id]


result = reframe(cancerdf, age=50:floor(t_c),.by = id) ----> this is exactly what I was doing, my only issue is that I want to keep the decimal values in the ages.

your desired result does not show that. please update your post to show exactly what your desired output should be.

Edit:
An even easier way:
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  reframe(t_c = 50:floor(t_c))

The easiest way I can think of doing this involves the tidyr's uncount. Simply subtract the age by the 50 and add 1 for an additional row for the age 50 itself to get the number of rows we want for each id. Then, you can use uncount to create those rows and a numeric id within each group. Reverse the process to get the ages.
This way you wouldn't lose any other columns:
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  t_c = c(75.41888, 90.89741, 55.75988, 94.59065, 94.2281)
)

df %>%
  mutate(count = floor(t_c - 49)) %>%
  uncount(count, .id = "t_c") %>%
  mutate(t_c = 49 + t_c)
#>     id t_c
#> 1    1  50
#> 2    1  51
#> 3    1  52
#> 4    1  53
#> 5    1  54
#> 6    1  55
#> 7    1  56
#> 8    1  57
#> 9    1  58
#> 10   1  59
#> 11   1  60
#> 12   1  61
#> 13   1  62
#> 14   1  63
#> 15   1  64
#> 16   1  65
#> 17   1  66
#> 18   1  67
#> 19   1  68
#> 20   1  69
#> 21   1  70
#> 22   1  71
#> 23   1  72
#> 24   1  73
#> 25   1  74
#> 26   1  75
#> 27   2  50
#> 28   2  51
#> 29   2  52
#> 30   2  53
#> 31   2  54
#> 32   2  55
#> 33   2  56
#> 34   2  57
#> 35   2  58
#> 36   2  59
#> 37   2  60
#> 38   2  61
#> 39   2  62
#> 40   2  63
#> 41   2  64
#> 42   2  65
#> 43   2  66
#> 44   2  67
#> 45   2  68
#> 46   2  69
#> 47   2  70
#> 48   2  71
#> 49   2  72
#> 50   2  73
#> 51   2  74
#> 52   2  75
#> 53   2  76
#> 54   2  77
#> 55   2  78
#> 56   2  79
#> 57   2  80
#> 58   2  81
#> 59   2  82
#> 60   2  83
#> 61   2  84
#> 62   2  85
#> 63   2  86
#> 64   2  87
#> 65   2  88
#> 66   2  89
#> 67   2  90
#> 68   3  50
#> 69   3  51
#> 70   3  52
#> 71   3  53
#> 72   3  54
#> 73   3  55
#> 74   4  50
#> 75   4  51
#> 76   4  52
#> 77   4  53
#> 78   4  54
#> 79   4  55
#> 80   4  56
#> 81   4  57
#> 82   4  58
#> 83   4  59
#> 84   4  60
#> 85   4  61
#> 86   4  62
#> 87   4  63
#> 88   4  64
#> 89   4  65
#> 90   4  66
#> 91   4  67
#> 92   4  68
#> 93   4  69
#> 94   4  70
#> 95   4  71
#> 96   4  72
#> 97   4  73
#> 98   4  74
#> 99   4  75
#> 100  4  76
#> 101  4  77
#> 102  4  78
#> 103  4  79
#> 104  4  80
#> 105  4  81
#> 106  4  82
#> 107  4  83
#> 108  4  84
#> 109  4  85
#> 110  4  86
#> 111  4  87
#> 112  4  88
#> 113  4  89
#> 114  4  90
#> 115  4  91
#> 116  4  92
#> 117  4  93
#> 118  4  94
#> 119  5  50
#> 120  5  51
#> 121  5  52
#> 122  5  53
#> 123  5  54
#> 124  5  55
#> 125  5  56
#> 126  5  57
#> 127  5  58
#> 128  5  59
#> 129  5  60
#> 130  5  61
#> 131  5  62
#> 132  5  63
#> 133  5  64
#> 134  5  65
#> 135  5  66
#> 136  5  67
#> 137  5  68
#> 138  5  69
#> 139  5  70
#> 140  5  71
#> 141  5  72
#> 142  5  73
#> 143  5  74
#> 144  5  75
#> 145  5  76
#> 146  5  77
#> 147  5  78
#> 148  5  79
#> 149  5  80
#> 150  5  81
#> 151  5  82
#> 152  5  83
#> 153  5  84
#> 154  5  85
#> 155  5  86
#> 156  5  87
#> 157  5  88
#> 158  5  89
#> 159  5  90
#> 160  5  91
#> 161  5  92
#> 162  5  93
#> 163  5  94

Created on 2024-07-14 with reprex v2.1.1

base R would look like this
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  t_c = c(75.41888, 90.89741, 55.75988, 94.59065, 94.2281)
)
df <- cbind(
  df[rep(1:nrow(df), floor(df$t_c)-50 + 1),],
  age = unlist(sapply(floor(df$t_c), seq, from = 50))
)


this is exactly what I was trying to do but I keep getting an invalid 'times' argument error

invalid 'times' argument error tend occur when the second argument of the rep method is (or becomes) negativ of NA. Difficult to help without an extended MWE.
